# Apply jQuery functions to appended Infinite Scroll elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm having an incredibly hard time finding an answer to this. There must be an answer buried somewhere, but I haven't found it yet.

In short, I have elements being appended to a Wordpress loop using Infinite Scroll. However I'm not using Isotope or Masonry plugins for this loop, which is where I'm being buried in wrong answers.

Outside of my header script to call Infinite Scroll, I have a slew of other functions being loaded with the `(window).load(function(){...` and from what I understand, the appended elements should fall into scope.

Unfortunately they're not.

My question is, shouldn't `(window).load` execute on every applicable element even after new Ajax elements have been appended?

Code available on request, but I'm hoping this is a simple syntax answer...

Comment: AFAIK, `$(window).load()` only fires once. `load` events on most elements don't bubble, if they fire at all. If you're looking to bind events, I would use event delegation. Otherwise, run your setup scripts in the ajax success or done handler.

Comment: If you're using the right plugin I'm thinking of there's a callback: $(elem).infinitescroll(options,[callback]);

Comment: @JasonP so... much... effort... haha thanks. You've shed light on the issue. Still hoping there's a less-code-more-results answer though. Fingers crossed on successful load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: no, `$(window).load()` doesn't fire when elements are appended, but only when the `window` object's `onload` event fires, i.e., at completion of initial page load.

The suggestion of event delegation is well founded, and that of passing a callback when instantiating the infinite scroller, even more so. Assuming you're using [this jQuery infinite scroll plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/), you might do something like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // [...]
    $('#infinite-scroll-element')
        .infinitescroll({ /* options */ },
                        // callback to handle binding events on newly added elements
                        function(newElements) {
                            // iterate across the elements just added
                            for (var i = 0; i < newElements.length; i++) {
                                var thisElement = newElements[i];
                                // bind your event handlers here, e.g.:
                                $(thisElement).click(function(evt) { /* ... */ });
                                $(thisElement).mouseover(function(evt) { /* ... */ });
                            };
                        });
    // [...]
};
```

Other plugins would presumably offer some similar functionality.

Comment: Ah glorious clarification at it's best. Great documentation here and this does the service of opening up the question of, why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @canacast Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ along with masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/ following code worked for me:

```
 $grid.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path, items ) {
        $(this).next(".info").slideToggle("fast"); 
      // OR your code you want to load after infinite scroll loads
    });
```

Check out here https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html#append